# coloring faces surrounding a given vertex index in THREE.js's Tube Geometry

Tags: three.js

I am modifying a vertex's coordinate in tube geometry and want to highlight that by coloring the faces surrounding that vertex, I have the index of the vertex. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

If you enable vertexColors on the material, you can then set the color of individual faces like

```
Geometry.faces[faceindex].color = new THREE.Color(0xFF00FF);
```

Comment: I am using this as material: var tubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(tube, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
                { color: 0x0ffff0, shading: THREE.FlatShading, side: THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: false, transparent: false,
                    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: false
                }));  if I change the vertex at 'idx' then 4 faces(faceindexes) colors needs to be changed surrounding that vertex. how do I calculate those 4 faceindexes.

Comment: Loop the array of faces, and check if a/b/c is equal to your vertex index to find touching faces.